# Reference request: English translation of Brieskorn 1970 paper

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, singularity-theory, translation

Is there any english (or french) translation of the following paper by Brieskorn (1970)?

Brieskorn, E., "Die Monodromie der Isolierten Singularitäten von Hyperflächen", Manuscripta Mathematica 2 (1970).

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

[Zentralblatt](http://zmath.sub.uni-goettingen.de/ZMATH/msc/en/search/zmath/?an=0209.348*) lists a translation in Russian [published in *Matematika, Moskva 15, No.4, 130-160 (1971)*], but that's all. I also checked the [Brieskorn Anniversary Volume,](https://books.google.nl/books?id=mskACAAAQBAJ&dq=moskva+brieskorn) which lists his complete works, and again only the Russian translation appears.

---

As suggested by @aginensky, here is how Google translates the introduction of the [Brieskorn paper](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/brieskorn7.pdf) from German into English. I give the translation without any post processing, directly as it comes out of the Google translator. It seems like a viable road.

> John Milnor has shown in [29] that can be topologically define a local
>   Picard-Lefschetz monodromy for singularities of hypersurfaces and
>   isolated that this monodromy up to a certain extent determines the
>   topology of the singularity. On the other hand there is the
>   Picard-Lefschetz monodromy of families of singular algebraic manifolds
>   investigations of A. Borel, C.H. Clemens [5] Ph.A. Griffiths [12],
>   [13], [14], A. Grothendieck [16], N.M. Katz [20], [21], A. Landman
>   [22] and F. Pham [31], which the classical results of Picard [32] and
>   Lefschetz [24] generalize. In particular, by Grothendieck and others
>   for this purpose an algebraic theory was developed, the theory of
>   Gauss-Manin connection. While this theory, however, families of
>   manifolds without singularities presupposes one-parameter families of
>   manifolds with singularities are examined in this paper, it is
>   introduced a singular local Gauass-Manin connectivity for isolated
>   singularities of hypersurfaces. This provides a purely algebraic
>   calculation of the originally defined topologically local
>   Picard-Lefschetz monodromy. The restriction to the special case of
>   isolated singularities of hypersurfaces the theory is very simple and
>   explicit.

and here is the French translation

> John Milnor a montré dans [29] qui peut être définie topologiquement
>   un monodromie locale Picard-Lefschetz de singularités des
>   hypersurfaces isolé et que cette monodromie jusqu'à une certaine
>   mesure détermine la topologie de la singularité. D'autre part, il ya
>   la monodromie Picard-Lefschetz des familles de singulières collecteurs
>   algébriques enquêtes de A. Borel, C.H. Clemens [5] Ph.A. Griffiths
>   [12], [13], [14], A. Grothendieck [16], N.M. Katz [20], [21], A.
>   Landman [22] et F. Pham [31], dont les résultats classiques de Picard
>   [32] et Lefschetz [24] généraliser. En particulier, par Grothendieck
>   et d'autres à cet effet une théorie algébrique a été développé, la
>   théorie de la connexion de Gauss-Manin. Bien que cette théorie,
>   cependant, les familles des collecteurs sans singularités suppose
>   familles à un paramètre de collecteurs avec singularités sont
>   examinées dans le présent document, il est introduit une connectivité
>   locale singulière Gauass-Manin pour les singularités isolées de
>   hypersurfaces. Cela fournit un calcul purement algébrique de la
>   monodromie Picard-Lefschetz topologiquement locale défini à l'origine.
>   La restriction au cas particulier des singularités isolées de
>   hypersurfaces la théorie est très simple et explicite.

Comment: Thank you for your search anyway. It is unfortunate that a foundational and widely known paper like this has no translation, I'm still hoping there is some "unofficial" english version somewhere. Meanwhile, I'll sit down with a German vocabulary...

Comment: What about using google translate ?